# The program ends straight away, why?

Tags: c++, c, audio

This code is supposed to repeatedly check the state of the D9 slider on an Axiom keyboard and use its value to control the pitch of a frequency.

```
int main()
{
    int note;
    int modwheel;
    float frequency;


    while (modwheel != 0)

    {
        note = aserveGetControl(74);
        modwheel = aserveGetControl(01);

        frequency = 440 * pow(2, (note-69) /12.0);
        aserveOscillator(1,frequency,1.0,0);
        aserveSleep(100);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to initialise `modwheel` before testing its value. You also forgot to enable your compiler's warnings.

Comment: You also forgot to decide whether you're using C or C++.

Comment: Well it can be either.

Comment: Also note that `01` is an octal constant - it doesn't matter in this instance, but you need to be aware of it, otherwise you'll get very confused when one day you try to use a value such as `012`.

Comment: It is C, I thought I'd tag it with both

Comment: Don't do that - C and C++ are very different languages and in general you will get very different answers for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize `modwheel`, so when the `while` loop starts, its value is "random", i.e. it can be zero, which causes the loop to end immediately.

Use a `do/while` loop to ensure it has at least one iteration, or use an infinite `while (true)` loop with an `if` inside to avoid actually handling `0` as valid input.